# Value Not entering in Key-value pair in Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, ecmascript-6

I have a json file:

```
var records= 
[
    {
        "category" : "chinese",
        "name": "noodles"
    },
    {
        "category" : "chinese",
        "name": "veg"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "Indian",
        "name": "Dal"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "Indian",
        "name": "Rajma"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "chinese",
        "name": "chicken"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "continental",
        "name": "fish"
    },
    {
        "category" : "continental",
        "name": "Veg"
    },
    {
        "category" : "Indian",
        "name": "Paratha" 
    }
]
```

I am trying to convert this JSON to following format:

```
var newcat = 
{
   "chinese": [
               { "name": "noodles", "category": "chinese" },
               {"name": "veg", "category": "chinese"}, 
               {"name":"chicken", "category": "chinese"}
            ], 
   "indian":  [
               { "name": "Dal", "category": "indian" },
               {"name": "rajma", "category": "indian"}, 
               {"name":"chicken", "category": "indian" }
            ], 
  "continental": [
                 { "name": "fish", "category": "continental" },
                 { "name": "veg", "category": "continental"} 

            ] 
}
```

The code I am using in angular is :

```
var newcat={}
            var arr= {}
            var isPresent= false;
            var cat
            for (let i=0;i< records.length;i++) {
                cat= records[i].category
                for(let item in newcat) {
                    if(cat == item) {
                        isPresent= true
                    }
                    else {
                            isPresent= false
                    }
                }
                if(isPresent== false){
                    newcat[cat]= []
                }
                else {
                    newcat[cat].push(records[i])
                    console.log("===>",newcat)
                }

            }
```

I am able to build the object except that, all the items of each category are not entering the new object **newcat**.

The result should come like this on console.log:

```
{chinese: Array(3), indian: Array(3), continental: Array(2)}
```

Instead it is coming like :

```
{chinese: Array(0), indian: Array(1), continental: Array(1)}
```

I couldn't figure out why all the elements are not entering

Comment: You could use Lodash's [`groupBy` function](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy).

Comment: @SimpleJ can't it be done by this way?

Comment: Yes it's possible to implement it yourself.

Comment: Using lodash isn't necessary for this when you can map and use spread operators with ecmascript-6.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using Lodash already, use [`_.groupBy`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.10#groupBy). Otherwise, you could write your own `groupBy` function:

```js
var records = [
    {
        "category" : "chinese",
        "name": "noodles"
    },
    {
        "category" : "chinese",
        "name": "veg"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "Indian",
        "name": "Dal"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "Indian",
        "name": "Rajma"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "chinese",
        "name": "chicken"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "continental",
        "name": "fish"
    },
    {
        "category" : "continental",
        "name": "Veg"
    },
    {
        "category" : "Indian",
        "name": "Paratha" 
    }
];

function groupBy(array, key) {
  return array.reduce((groups, value) => {
    const group = groups[value[key]] || (groups[value[key]] = []);
    group.push(value);
    return groups;
  }, {});
}

console.log(groupBy(records, 'category'));
```

Alternatively, with a `for` loop instead of `reduce`:

```js
function groupBy(array, key) {
  const groups = {};
  for(let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    const value = array[i];
    const valueKey = value[key];
    if(!groups[valueKey]) groups[valueKey] = [];
    groups[valueKey].push(value);
  }
  return groups;
}
```

**EDIT: Fixing your existing code:**

Your implementation has two issues. First, the `for/in` loop that sets `isPresent` doesn't `break` after it finds a match. Second, the `else` statement at the end causes the first item in a category to not be pushed because all you do is create the empty category array. Here it is with fixes:

```js
var records = [
    {
        "category" : "chinese",
        "name": "noodles"
    },
    {
        "category" : "chinese",
        "name": "veg"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "Indian",
        "name": "Dal"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "Indian",
        "name": "Rajma"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "chinese",
        "name": "chicken"  
    },
    {
        "category" : "continental",
        "name": "fish"
    },
    {
        "category" : "continental",
        "name": "Veg"
    },
    {
        "category" : "Indian",
        "name": "Paratha" 
    }
];


var newcat = {};
var arr = {};
var isPresent = false;
var cat;

for (let i=0; i < records.length; i++) {
    cat= records[i].category
    for(let item in newcat) {
        if(cat == item) {
            isPresent= true
            break;
        }
        else {
            isPresent= false
        }
    }
    if(isPresent== false){
        newcat[cat] = []
    }
    newcat[cat].push(records[i])
}

console.log(newcat);
```

Comment: It did work. But since I am just getting started and learning angular, It would be a great help if you could help me to correct the loops I wrote. If I could figure out the mistakes it will be very helpful

Comment: There are two issues I can see with your solution. First: the `for/in` loop doesn't break after it finds a matching `cat` value, so it sets `isPresent` to `false` after it finds a match. Second: the `else` statement at the end keeps the item from being pushed if it's the first item. I'll add your solution with fixes to this answer.

Comment: Ya, now i could figure it out. Thank you a lot :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are using ecmascript-6 as tagged, you should have access to the spread operator without the heaviness of using Lodash:

This should essentially do all of the work for you:

```
records.map(item => {
    newcat[item.category.toLowerCase()] = newcat[item.category.toLowerCase()] || []
    newcat[item.category.toLowerCase()] = [
        ...newcat[item.category.toLowerCase()],
        { ...item }
    ] 
})
```

Working snippet below:

```js
var records = [{
    "category": "chinese",
    "name": "noodles"
  },
  {
    "category": "chinese",
    "name": "veg"
  },
  {
    "category": "Indian",
    "name": "Dal"
  },
  {
    "category": "Indian",
    "name": "Rajma"
  },
  {
    "category": "chinese",
    "name": "chicken"
  },
  {
    "category": "continental",
    "name": "fish"
  },
  {
    "category": "continental",
    "name": "Veg"
  },
  {
    "category": "Indian",
    "name": "Paratha"
  }
]

var newcat = {}

records.map(item => {
  newcat[item.category.toLowerCase()] = newcat[item.category.toLowerCase()] || []
  newcat[item.category.toLowerCase()] = [
    ...newcat[item.category.toLowerCase()],
    { ...item }
  ]
})

console.log(newcat)
```